# Swipe to answer local notification doesn't always bring app to foreground

Tags: ios, uikit, uilocalnotification

My iOS7 app listens for incoming request, and triggers a local notification when it happens using standard code:

```
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
[notification setFireDate:[NSDate date]];
[notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[notification setAlertBody:@"Incoming data"];
[notification setAlertAction:@"Respond"];
[notification setSoundName:@"incoming-ring2.m4a"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

The notification appears correctly when the iPad is locked and the sound is played.

The problem is that swiping the notification to respond doesn't always bring my app to the foreground. I've narrowed it down as follows:

1. App was in the foreground when the lock button was pressed - always returns to my app
2. App was backgrounded when the lock button was pressed and I swipe the notification immediately - always returns to my app
3. App was backgrounded when the lock button was pressed and I wait until the sound has played out before swiping - always returns to Springboard, not my app.

As a work around, I trigger a few local notifications so that if the swipe takes the user to Springboard, there's another notification a short while later that they can use to get into the application, but this is a hack.

Does anyone have any ideas why it's not working in the 3rd case?

Comment: `My iOS7 app listens for incoming request` please elaborate

Comment: Sorry, it's a VoIP app, it listens for incoming call requests/other events